# Why is my JavaScript code showing different behavior on jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javaScript, that's why I am unable to find the real root cause for it. 
This simple code is to append the value of a button into a paragraph every time i press it; however if the paragraph contains only a zero then it should replace the value, not append.

1. This is working fine on all of my browsers and also when running the snippet on stackoverflow .
2. Not working at all on https://jsfiddle.net/

Can you please tell me why I am facing this problem and what changes should I make to make it work on every platform?

```js
function append(a){
  if (document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML == '0')
    document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML = document.getElementById(a).value;
    else
    document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML += document.getElementById(a).value;
};
```

```html
<div>
<p id='text1' style="border-style: inset;
         width:200px;
         display:inline-block;">0</p><br>
<button value="1" id='a1' onclick="append(this.id)">1</button></div>
```

Comment: In JSFiddle, you need to change your JavaScript *Load Type* to `No wrap - in <body>`. By default, scripts on JSFiddle are wrapped within a document load handler, therefore `append` is not declared in the same scope as the element.

Comment: Because jsFiddle thought it would be a good idea to put all your JS code inside a function without making it clear. So your `append()` function isn't global. As a result of their design decision, there are hundreds of questions like yours on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

By default JSFiddle wraps your JavaScript in an `onload` function. This means that `function append` is only defined in that scope, and is not made global.

Global variables (and functions) are generally considered bad practice, as are inline event handlers.

Try:

```
document.getElementById('a1').onclick = append;
```

Then, inside `function append`, simply refer to `this.value`.